# CSS sprites positioning inside a button

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Look at the following code:

```
<div class="features">
    <h1>BLAH BLAH</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <span class="navigate-best"><img class="gourmet">Gourmet</span>
        </li>
        <li>
           <span class="navigate-best"><img class="north">North</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the html. Below is the CSS

```
.features ul li  span img{
    background: url(../images/result.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.gourmet{
    background-position: -0px -400px;
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;
}

.dessert{
    background-position: -0px -108px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Actually `navigate-best` is a class that displays a link like a button and I am trying to add
images at the left end of each button using CSS sprites.

Say that for the button named 'Gourmet' I have class called `gourmet`  and the corresponding  image in the sprite is at `-0px -400px` but this does not work. All I am getting is the first image in the sprite. This happens for every button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it be the specificity of your selectors?  What if you define the different parts of background (i.e. background-image) in `.features ul li  span img`?  Or, try adding `!important` to the '.gourmet' `background-position: 0px -400px !important;`

Comment: Pls. Add a JSFiddle with all data with `result.png`.

Comment: specificity is the point. @Tim Tim is right.

Comment: also, you don't usually see `background-image` being used on an `img` tag.  What if you change it to a `<div>`?

Comment: Ok so far what I have done is correct right?

Comment: I would say no.  The CSS engine is preferring the `background` declaration over your `background-position` declaration.  Defining `background` in a more specific selector is "overwriting" your `background-image` declaration in a less specific selector.  At least, I think this is what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) issue.

```
.features ul li span img{
    background: url(../images/result.png) no-repeat;
    border:0 none; /* Oh god no!! In google chrome a border is being added to the images. */
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Try this :

```
.features ul li span img.gourmet{
    background-position: -0px -400px;
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;
}

.features ul li span img.dessert{
    background-position: -0px -108px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

But for sure, without a working example such as a jsFiddle, i am unable to tell you for sure what's your situation and that what i suggest will fix it.

Comment: I tried adding JS fiddle but my its downtime here, I cant do anything with fiddle. Can you please help me now?. If not possible then I will add a fiddle tomorrow morning that is +8 hours from now

Comment: bloody hell!! It works now. I tried the same thing, I swear it did not work therefore I posted this question. Now its working. I dont know khow.

Comment: Oh god no!! In google chrome a border is being added to the images. Its working fine now but borders are being added to the images

Comment: Just add 'border:0 none' to ".features ul li span img" declaration.